# In Anno 2070, which NPC cannot go to war?

Tags: anno-2070

I was playing a modified medium continuous game with Bartok and she declared war on me based on an ultimatum.  If I want to play a continuous game, which NPCs should I pick so that there are no military conflicts at all?  I'm ok with them fighting each other as long as I'm not dragged in their conflicts.

I understand that turning off quests can get rid of the above issue but I want to play a quiet, peaceful continuous game with some quests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These NPCs are non-expanding and never go to war. They only have an Ark, sell things, and give you quests. Select these to basically have a sandbox game.

- Devi
- Yanna
- Thorne
- Hibashi
- Trenchcoat

Keto and Scorpio are also non-expanding, but always start at war with you. Don't pick them.

All other NPCs are expanding and will go to war over *something*, but you might not meet that requirement. For example, Leon and Tilda are usually very passive unless you build nuclear power. If you're playing as Ecos, you'll never have this problem.